# How to make ColorDialog to allow to set chosen color's transparency?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, color-picker

I don't see any fields available for that.
I tried all this:

```
        ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
        cd.AnyColor = true;
        cd.AllowFullOpen = true;
        cd.SolidColorOnly = false;
```

but it probably does something else.

If it impossible to do so with win forms control, maybe there is WPF color picker that I could use in WPFHost element?

Comment: The `ColorDialog` doesn't support transparency. However, as a long time front end developer I would always have transparency aka alpha channel **outside and separate** of color picker or color for that matter. Maybe you're thinking as a programmer but in end-user mindset transparency has nothing to do with color. Of course that is very subjective but do think about it.

Comment: @bokibeg - Um, for me is easer to think about transparency as one of the color properties... and paint.net somehow offers to set transparency in it's color palette window :(

Comment: They've probably placed a hook on it, luckily for you it's open source so you can easily see how they did it :).

Comment: You could try https://sourceforge.net/projects/alpha-color-dialog/

Comment: @Loathing - even though I solved this long ago by creating my own color dialog, your solution is good. So make it as answer and I accept it.

Comment: @Kosmos Thanks, posted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AlphaColorDialog` project can be downloaded from sourceforge at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/alpha-color-dialog/

Source `C#` files are in the `src` folder in the zip file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try these ones from Cyotek, it has series of controls including a dialog with Alpha and other controls

http://www.cyotek.com/blog/colorpicker-controls-for-windows-forms

[image]